# Posso usar a tag <details> para compor uma <nav>?

Tags: html5, menu, seo

É possível usar a tag `<details>` dentro de uma `<nav>` como um menu dropdown? Ou não é muito semântico para o SEO?

Exemplo:

```
<nav>
    <details>
        <summary>Menu</summary>
        <a href="#">Link 1</a>        
        <details>
            <summary>Sessão 1</summary>
            <a href="#">Link 3</a>
        </details>
        <a href="#">Link 4</a>
        <a href="#">Link 5</a>
    </details>        
</nav>
```

Comment: Acho que com relação ao Seo pode não ser tão critico quanto para questões de acessibilidade. Mas algo que vc deve procurar saber eh como o Google indexa na serp um componente desse tipo, pois ele não deve comportar os metadados que seriam relativos a uma Nav

Comment: Semântica e SEO não são 2 assuntos "exatamente" relacionados, apesar de que fazer um site mais organizado pode facilitar, mas você pode ter pensado em fazer algo que é claro, sendo que na verdade não é, a questão é, funciona bem para o usuário independente de JS, então provavelmente vai funcionar bem para os "indexadores" (ao menos o google), de resto existem sitemaps e afins que ajudam. Melhorar um menu ou HTML não vai te por na frente, nem fazer um bom html em geral, busca orgânica é algo que demanda tempo, investimento e conhecimento.